# Can I look up a large list of cards on MagicCardMarket.eu?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

MagicCardMarket.eu is apparently the go-to store for buying Magic cards in Europe, and I'm using it for the first time. I've a list of cards I'd like to buy to finalise a deck, and I can't find any way to search for them except one by one.

Other card sellers I was used to using in another country let me input my entire want list and search for *all* those cards at once -- and it'd make suggestions for each one. I gather I can set up a want list so that sellers can contact me, but that's an advertising mecahnism, not a search mechanism — I want to search for all cards on a list I've got.

Comment: I'm not really sure if this is on-topic or would be considered off-topic for Board & Card games. It kind of makes sense for it to be posted here but I haven't seen anything similar to it before for MTG. I posted [a question on the meta](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1610/15514) if you think it should be discussed further.

Comment: @Malco Thanks for the invitation to respond to that. I'll follow that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to JonTheMon in chat I've been able to find out how to get to this feature. It's a registration-only feature hidden behind another feature.

The basic steps are: register → set up a [wants list](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Help/Wants_List) → via that wants list, enter the [shopping wizard](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Help/Shopping_Wizard).

## The detailed steps

1. Register an account. You can't access the feature anonymously yet.
2. Once your account is registered and verified, mouse over the **Buying** menu and pick **My Wants** from the dropdown.
3. Once on the Wants screen you'll see nothing other than the option to create a "new list" with a single input. This input will be used to name the list itself:

   [image: New List. Name input. Plus button.]

   Enter the name of your list here and hit the plus button. In my case I named the list after the deck I was buying cards for, and called it "hapatra wants". You can set up other Want lists later, or delete them.
4. Once your list is created you'll see the screen below. Hit **Add Deck List** for mass adding:

   [image: "You haven't added cards to your wants list yet." Below that -- "Add deck list".]
5. Enter your cards in the **1x Card name** format and hit the plus when you want to add them:

   [image]
6. You'll see a confirmation below, and can hit the small "back to your wants list" button at the bottom:

   [image]
7. Now that your wants list is set up, you can hit **Shopping Wizard**:

   [image: located below the tabular list of cards]

From the shopping list you can configure how you want to search, and it'll produce one or more batches of cards from sellers matching your criteria.